# using one or the other when adding to a database field

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system

Im creating myself a CMS which I have added an upload page.

what I am trying to do is add 2 input types on to my ADD.PHP form. The first is to add an image using the upload button.

The second one is to add an image using a URL.

Both of these should be saved to the same promo_image within my MOBI database in mysql.

What I would like is for the URL version to be priority for if both the fields are entered.

The code I currently have for this ADD.PHP page is:

```
<?php

session_start();

include_once('../include/connection.php');

if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
      if (isset($_POST['title'], $_POST['content'])) {
             $title = $_POST['title'];
             $content = nl2br($_POST['content']);
             $image = $_POST['image'];
             $imageupload = $_POST['image'];
             $link = $_POST['link'];
             $category = $_POST['category'];
             $brand = $_POST['brand'];

if (empty($title) or empty($content)) {
             $error = 'All Fields Are Required!';
}else{
     $query = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO mobi (promo_title, promo_content, promo_image, promo_link, promo_cat, promo_name) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
     $query->bindValue(1, $title);
     $query->bindValue(2, $content);
     $query->bindValue(3, if(trigger){empty(["image"])} else {"imageupload"});
     $query->bindValue(4, $link);
     $query->bindValue(5, $category);
     $query->bindValue(6, $brand);

     $query->execute();
    header('location: index.php');
}

}
          ?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Add Article</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../other.css" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<a href="index.php" id="logo"><b>&larr; Back</b></a>

<br />

<div align="center">
<h4>Add Article</h4>

<?php if (isset($error)) { ?>
     <small style="color:#aa0000;"><?php echo $error; ?></small><br /><br />
<?php } ?>

<form action="add.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">

<input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" /><br /><br />
<textarea rows="15" cols="50" placeholder="Content" name="content"></textarea><br /><br />
<input name="imageupload" type="file" id="image" placeholder="Imageupload" />
<input type="text" name="image" placeholder="Image" /><br /><br />
<input type="link" name="link" placeholder="Link" /><br /><br />
<input type="category" name="category" placeholder="Category" /><br /><br />
<input type="category" name="brand" placeholder="Brand" /><br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Add Article" />

</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>


<?php
}else{
       header('location: index.php');
}

?>
```

As it currently stands I am getting the error of:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in admin/add.php on line 23
```

Im just not so sure on how to do it. please can someone help. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This uses an PHP short if/else syntax:

```
$query->bindValue(3, !empty($image) ? $image : $imageupload);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your $image and $imageupload are the same value so the if statement is redundant? try the following.

UPDATE for file upload (you were missing enctype from form tag. also make sure the targetpath directory exists and is set to chmod 777

```
<?php
session_start();

include_once('../include/connection.php');

if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in']))
{
    if (isset($_POST['title'], $_POST['content']))
    {
        $title   = $_POST['title'];
        $content = nl2br($_POST['content']);
        if (!empty($_POST['image']))
        {
            $image = $_POST['image'];
        }
        else
        {
            $image = $_POST['imageupload'];

            if (isset($_FILES['Filedata']))
            {
                $filename   = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
                $targetpath = "../put/path/here" . $filename; //target directory relative to script location

                $copy = copy($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'], $targetpath);

                if (!$copy)
                    $error = "Image was not uploaded successfully";
            }
        }
        $link     = $_POST['link'];
        $category = $_POST['category'];
        $brand    = $_POST['brand'];

        if (empty($title) or empty($content))
        {
            $error = 'All Fields Are Required!';
        }
        else
        {
            $query = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO mobi (promo_title, promo_content, promo_image, promo_link, promo_cat, promo_name) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
            $query->bindValue(1, $title);
            $query->bindValue(2, $content);
            $query->bindValue(3, $image);
            $query->bindValue(4, $link);
            $query->bindValue(5, $category);
            $query->bindValue(6, $brand);

            $query->execute();
            header('location: index.php');
        }
    }
    ?>

    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Add Article</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="../other.css" />
        </head>

        <body>
            <div class="container">
                <a href="index.php" id="logo"><b>&larr; Back</b></a>

                <br />

                <div align="center">
                    <h4>Add Article</h4>

                    <?php if (isset($error))
                    { ?>
                        <small style="color:#aa0000;"><?php echo $error; ?></small><br /><br />
    <?php } ?>

                    <form action="add.php" method="post" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                        <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" /><br /><br />
                        <textarea rows="15" cols="50" placeholder="Content" name="content"></textarea><br /><br />
                        <input name="imageupload" type="file" id="image" placeholder="Imageupload" />
                        <input type="text" name="image" placeholder="Image" /><br /><br />
                        <input type="link" name="link" placeholder="Link" /><br /><br />
                        <input type="category" name="category" placeholder="Category" /><br /><br />
                        <input type="category" name="brand" placeholder="Brand" /><br /><br />
                        <input type="submit" value="Add Article" />

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>


    <?php
}
else
{
    header('location: index.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: Ok. my trouble now tho is this: this works like a charm but it does not actually upload the image. Lets say my file was called XXXXXXXX.jpg on my computer. It reads the file but does not save it to the system. How can I get it to save the image in my /images folder automatically? thanks.

Comment: hi. where is best to add that? i have tried a few locations but had no success.

Comment: Still no joy. not saving images at all.

Comment: /images/ and the folder is created.

Comment: have you chmod 777 on the folder? is the folder in the same directory as the php script?

Comment: The folder and the add page are both within the same admin file yes. What do you mean by chmod 777 its not something I am awair of. How do I use it?

Comment: you need to change the write permissions of the folder, can usually be done by right clicking on the folder within your ftp client